# Yii2 Remote Database Connection Issue

Tags: mysql, database, yii2, connection

I am trying to get my web server to connect to my remote database (Mysql).
The connection is happening in my web application which is built on yii2.

I have created all user details, GRANTED all privileges and allowed connections from ALL hosts (%) (Progressively in troubleshooting this).
[image: Imgur]

Now I can connect from home using HeidiSQL or using Mysql Workbench without issue.
I have even created a blank yii2 site at home and it works instantly, but uploading the site to the web server instantly gives the same issue.

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '46.105.111.111' (110)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '46.105.111.111' (110)

in /home/xxxxxxx/xtest.xxxxxxxx.tv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php at line 602
```

I have run netstat on the db server:
[image: Imgur]

I have been through the etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
<pre>[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]

user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 7999
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

#bind-address            = *
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

max_connections        = 65535
open-files-limit = 65535
max_connect_errors = 65535
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
table_open_cache = 1000

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 256M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M</pre>
```

I have looked at the iptables:
[image: Imgur]

I am totally bedazzled as having read about 20 pieces of information about mysql security, i get the feeling its a permissions issue.

I have even tried using my own PDO Wrapper, so i a, 99% sure its not a Yii2 issue, would really appreciate any help.

Hopefully I have provided enough info as I got a downvote previously.

Comment: Do mysql let you connect remotely ? Do you turn on remote mysql connection ?

Comment: Yes as shown above, remote connection is enabled and I can in-fact connect from home with no problem at all.

Comment: Shouldn't there be port 3306 on netstat? Oh, right, it's set to 7999.

Comment: can you connect from command line on the server using ```mysql``` command?

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for the help.

It turns out that the web host was actually blocking the outgoing port for the connection.

The output error from yii being database error, nievly led me to think the issue was at the database end.

Simple logic when you read back the question.

I would say to anyone that finds this question, remember with a connection issue that communication is two way, check both ends of the connection.